# Hive array with hbase in binary type with RegexSerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, delimiter

I tried to create a table using `RegexSerDe` because my data is bytes and my bytes are in collision with default delimiter.

```
CREATE  External TABLE f10(key string, arr array<string> )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("field.delimited"="[,]")
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,info:arr2" ) 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="f");
```

but some error :

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe only accepts string columns, but column[1] named arr has type array<string>)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Any idea ?
Any good delimiter?

Or Any good SERDE for this.

hive version 11

Comment: The error description is clear: the RegexSerde expects a string but the type of column 1 of your table f10 is an array. In addition, if your data is binaries, RegexSerde is not proper as it should be used to process Text data with defined regular expressions. Maybe you can have a look at LazyBinarySerDe?

Answer (score 0):

A storage handler comes with its own serde and input/output formats. I am not sure if specifying your own serde along with a storage handler will work.

I am trying to find an answer for a similar problem. Multi-byte delimiter in hbase table key or value are difficult to manage with hive.